# How do these recursively defined sets and their intersection look like?

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

Let $S_0:=\bigcup \{[n,n+1]\times [m,m+1]\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\; n-m\; \text{even}\}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2$, for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ let $S_k:=\frac{1}{3^k}S_0$ and $S:=([0,1]\times[0,1])\cap \bigcap_{k=1}^\infty S_k$.

I'm trying to understand the definition of $S$ and I'm already having trouble to understand how $S_1$ (or if it's better, $S_1\cap ([0,1]\times[0,1])$) and $S_2$ (and actually $S_1\cap S_2 \cap ([0,1]\times[0,1])$ ) look like. After

Regarding $S_1$: $S_1=\frac{1}{3}S_0$ and in $S_1\cap ([0,1]\times [0,1])$ is just $[0,\frac{1}{3}]\times [0,\frac{1}{3}]$, or is there more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_0$ is a checkerboard on the plane with squares of length 1. One of the squares in $S_0$ is $[0,1]^2$.

[image]

Subsequent $S_k$ are also checkerboards, but with squares of side $3^{-k}$ and having one square as $[0,3^{-k}]^2$.

Taking intersections of $[0,1]^2$ with successively more $S_k$ describes a fractal that starts with a square and repeatedly replaces each square with five squares of $\frac13$ the size in an X shape. The first two iterations of this fractal are shown below.

[image]